# Unable to set Single Line on Support library EditTextPreference

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-preferences, edittextpreference

I am currently using the support library version of EditTextPreference and I am unable to make the edit text dialog to be single line. Below is my code taken from `settings.xml`:

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/settings_extra_remarks_key"
        android:maxLength="@integer/free_text_maxlength"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:title="@string/settings_extra_remarks_title" />
```

As you can see I even added `imeOptions="actionDone"` to force the keyboard to not show an `ENTER` key but even the imeOptions does not work.

Help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is too old and deals with an earlier version of Android

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, so here's a brief answer.

The bugfix I created (https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix) now (*and has for a while*) forwards the attributes set on `EditTextPreference` to the `EditText` in the dialog. Also, if you import the `EditTextPreference` from `com.takisoft.fix.support.v7.preference` package instead of the official one, you'll have access to the `EditText` by calling `getEditText()` on the `EditTextPreference`.

*I wish Google fixed the problems, but it seems like they don't really care...*

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

there's a bugifx on github:
https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix

"So, Google gives us a solution which I think is not ideal but works. According to this, instead of using

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
```

one should use"

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
```

Comment: `getEditText()` does not exist in the support library EditTextPreference